# How to setup composer with fabric + kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm setting up a Hyperledger Fabric, with:
 1 org,
 2 orderers,
 2 peers,
 4 kafkas,
 3 zookeepers,
 1 certificate authority.

I followed the [fabric-samples-with-kafka](https://github.com/keenkit/fabric-sample-with-kafka) guide, but as I need hyperledger composer as well I added an additional CA to the docker compose file. After running `./startfabric` all of my containers start logging handshake failures: `2019-06-05 09:56:23.215 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 20c grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "192.168.96.6:49830": remote error: tls: bad certificate`. As this is a handshaking error I believe this is because the CA is setup incorrectly, my CA in the docker compose looks like this

```
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/071043b1f49c2df2e317c9679e0f15212bdf8ee7a193d021dbd8b3d29709eb5f_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/071043b1f49c2df2e317c9679e0f15212bdf8ee7a193d021dbd8b3d29709eb5f_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    # command: bash
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile $${FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE} --ca.keyfile $${FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE} -b Admin:adminpw '
    # command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b Admin:adminpw '
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Has anyone been successful in setting up fabric + kafka + composer, and is able to give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I would not go down this path at all given it looks like you are just starting out.
Why?

1. Fabric 1.2 is pretty old; we are now on Fabric 1.4.1 with 1.4.2 around the corner
2. Composer is no longer under active development; this is not marketing for IBM, but https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform is the replacement tool from the core team who built Composer but many facets of the programming model are now part of Fabric and the Fabric SDKs
3. Fabric 1.4.1 introduced Raft-based ordering which is much simpler to run and operate than the Kafka-based orderer